# How to use ngif so that it can hide a div and do not validate the elements under the div section?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Upon selecting a radio button the respective div should be visible. Again each div has its own HTML elements.

Currently I am using code like this

```
<div *ngIf="A.checked">
  show A HTML elements
</div>
<div *ngIf="B.checked">
  show B elements
</div>
```

It is working fine as it is hiding depending on selection, however when I submit , it is validating the hidden div elements. Please suggest me how to stop validating the elements under hidden div.?

Comment: What do you mean by "validating the hidden div elements"? You mean built-in html validation, or angular reactive forms validation?

Comment: Angular reactive forms

Answer (score 0):

Reactive forms don't look at the hidden status of elements.
You should update your validation based on user selection by:

```
form.setValidators([ ... /* validators that you want to set */ ]) 
form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: @hali any comments?

Comment: will let you know by next week as I am working on other things now.

Comment: I didnt use anything as you suggested. However, my code worked with just ngif and select event of radio button. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

```
// Define a Subject and destroy in onDestroy
private destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

someForm.get('controlname').valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(
  value ==> {
      if (value) {
         // Remove validators for unwanted controls
         someForm.get('unwantedControl').setValidators(null);
         someFrom.get('unwantedControl').updateValueAndVaildity();
      }
})


ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```